# Problem with the screen resolution on 12.04

Tags: xorg, resolution, xrandr

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop. The screen resolution is stuck in 1024x768.
The screen is made for 1280x800. When I run `xrandr` I get:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0
```

1280x800 isn't offered and I get gamma size error. I was going to look into the `Xorg.conf` file but I couldn't locate it.

1280x800 was displayed in Windows 7 and I think it is being displayed in Grub before Ubuntu starts also. Here are some details about my computer:

- CPU: Intel atom D2500 1.86GHz
- Chipset: Intel 945GSE+ICH7M
- LCD: 14" TFT 16:9
- Resolution ratio: 1280*800
- Video Card: Intel integrated GMA950

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to choosing correct driver package here:
[Linux Graphics Drivers from Intel](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/)

Possible solution is:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

**Other way:**

**Step 1.** Create mode line by using ***gtf***

Thus if your output have 61.0Hz frequency:

`gtf 1280 800 61.0` - this command will calculate your Modeline for 1280x800

**Step 2.** Create new mode for ***xrandr***

```
xrandr --newmode <value of your modeline without word "Modeline">
```

**Step 3.** Add new mode to output

```
xrandr --addmode VGA 1280x800_61.00
```

*And if commands above DON'T bring any errors:*

**Step 4.** Choose your new mode

```
xrandr --output VGA --mode 1280x800_61.00
```

Comment: I get an error about 'xserver-xorg' isn't installed. How do I fix it?